# How to sync NSAttributed string to MS Sharepoint server

Tags: html, ios, sharepoint, core-text, rich-text-editor

I have requirement where user edits notes for Rich text editing features. Then user syncs these notes to sharepoint. My question is, does sharepoint column type support storing an attributed string OR I would have to convert NSAttributed strings to HTML tags ? Does sharepoint support storing unicode character attributed strings OR HTML pages as column type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `NSAttributedString` to `NSData` using `NSKeyedArchiver` and upload:

```
NSString *theString = @"Example";
NSDictionary *theAttributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:26], NSFontAttributeName,
                               [NSColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
NSAttributedString *theAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] 
                                           initWithString:theString
                                           attributes: theAttributes];
NSData *theData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:theAttributedString];
```

Download the data from the server and convert it back to the `NSAttributedString` using:

```
NSAttributedString *theAttributedString = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:theData];
```

Generally I upload `NSAttributedStrings` in two formats:

- The archived `NSAttributedString` to make sure I can later retrieve exactly the same object.
- The plain version of the `NSAttributedString` to allow search and display server side.

Comment: Thanks Anne. What should be the column type on sharepoint if I want to store an archived NSAttributedString at sharepoint?